# Data URI imports in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

In plain JS we can use import statements with data uri, e.g.:

```
import { number, fn } from 'data:text/javascript;charset=utf-8;base64,ZXhwb3J0IGNvbnN0IG51bWJlciA9IDQyOwpleHBvcnQgY29uc3QgZm4gPSAoKSA9PiAiSGVsbG8gd29ybGQiOw==';
```

Or dynamically:

```
import('data:text/javascript;charset=utf-8;base64,ZXhwb3J0IGNvbnN0IG51bWJlciA9IDQyOwpleHBvcnQgY29uc3QgZm4gPSAoKSA9PiAiSGVsbG8gd29ybGQiOw==')
    .then(module => console.log(module));
```

However, putting the same code in a typescript file gets us a "Cannot find module" error.

My tsconfig.json is as follows:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "esnext",
        "lib": [
            "esnext",
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "./build",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "jsx": "react"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*", "../addon/build/background.js"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

Typescript docs on module resolution have no mention of data:... from what I see. Is there a way to get this to work in typescript?

Answer (score 1):

See [Wildcard module declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#wildcard-module-declarations) in the Typescript handbook.

You could do something like this:

```
// types.d.ts
declare module "data:text/javascript;*" {
  export const number: number;
  export function fn(): string;
}

// index.ts

/// <reference path="types.d.ts"/>
import { number, fn } from 'data:text/javascript;charset=utf-8;base64,ZXhwb3J0IGNvbnN0IG51bWJlciA9IDQyOwpleHBvcnQgY29uc3QgZm4gPSAoKSA9PiAiSGVsbG8gd29ybGQiOw==';
```

This tells Typescript that an import matching the `data:text/javascript;` prefix will expose a `number` property (as a number type) and an `fn` property (which returns a string). Adjust the module declaration to fit your importer semantics as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work for static imports, but dynamic one still fails. Regardless, you've put me onto the right track,  I've been thinking about this all wrong.